# AngularJS - How can i use a filtered array in another filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I use the filtered array in orderByName in the newFirst filter? Is this possible?

```
filter = (list | orderByName | newFirst )
```

I have a list sorted alphabetically and I need to sort again by if it's new or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. But you have to take care that the second ordering function doesn't override the result of the first one. The easiest way to achieve that, is with the standard `orderBy` filter of AngularJS with multiple sorting parameters:

Using object properties:

```
ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy:['name', 'isNew']"
```

Using custom comparators:

```
ng-repeat="item in list | orderBy:[orderByName, newFirst]"
```

For the second way you need to implement the functions `orderByName` and `newFirst` as comparator function (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Comment: Daniel , Thank you very much, for your help